# What happens to transaction if SessionScoped and Stateless method calls are mixed

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, cdi, stateless

What happens in following scenario if error occurred in `DStateless.method4()` or `BSession.method2()`? I want that `CStateless.method3()` and `DStateless.method4()` share the same transaction.

Is it permitted to make such calls in **EJB** and **CDI** ?

```
ASession.method1() (calls)-> CStateless.method3() -> BSession.method2() -> DStateless.method4();
```

---

```
@SessionScoped
class ASession {
   method1();
}

@SessionScoped
class BSession {
   method2();
}

@Stateless
class CStateless {
   method3();
}

@Stateless
class DStateless {
   method4();
}
```

Comment: In this case they will share the same transaction. The only question is why would you call a sessionscoped bean from a stateless bean

Comment: @maress The main reason is that sessionScoped bean makes some file operations. Another reason is session scoped bean has more informations about what to do.

Comment: That still does not warrant sessionscoped bean invocation from stateless bean. Do everything in session bean that requires session/request context and then upload the next logic to stateless bean. The session bean can potentially call several stateless beans to finish up its work

Comment: @maress yes session bean can call several stateless beans, but what to do if all calls should be in a single transaction ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's permitted.

Assuming that `method1()` is not running in a transaction, the transaction boundary will be around `method3()`. `method4()` will use the same transaction.